# Semaphore wait causing a block of AFNetworking?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, unit-testing, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to use unit testing to also test for networking. When called outside of my testing, the loginWithUserName:password: method properly fails and the outer failure block is called. When called from within my testing method, the failure block is never called (nor is the success block).

I think perhaps my semaphore wait is causing the networking to also wait, but I would't think so since it is on a different thread. I want it on a different thread so I can do an asynchronous call. Can I fix this to work properly? Should I use a different technique?

I have my test methods setup like this:

```
typedef void (^CompleteBlock)();

- (void)testLogin {
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [self callLoginWithCompletion:^{
        XCTAssertTrue(true, @"login Complete"); // expand on this when I get basic premise working
        NSLog(@"asserted true");
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}

- (void)callLoginWithCompletion:(CompleteBlock)completeBlock {
    NSLog(@"login method called");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kLoginComplete
                                                      object:nil
                                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                      completeBlock();
                                                  }];

    [Network loginWithUserName:@"dummyUser" password:@"dummyPassword"];
}
```

And my login method looks like this:
    static AFNetworkReachabilityManager *_reachabilityManager;

```
+ (AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *)gatewayClient {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _gatewayClient = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kGatewayBaseURL]];
        _gatewayClient.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];
    });

    AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
    securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
    [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager].securityPolicy = securityPolicy;

    return _gatewayClient;
}

+ (NSString *)baseURLForType:(NSString *)type method:(NSString *)method {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"api/%@/%@", type, method];
}

+ (void)loginWithUserName:(NSString *)userName password:(NSString *)password {
    [Network.gatewayClient
     GET:[self baseURLForType:@"auth"
                       method:@"getpubtoken"]
     parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         _authToken = responseObject;

         NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                      @"UserId": userName
                                      , @"Password": password
                                      , kApiVersion: kApiVersion
                                      , kApiKey: kApiKeyValue
                                      , kAuthToken: _authToken
                                      , kFundraisingPlatform: @(Blackbaud)
                                      };

         [Network.gatewayClient
          POST:[self baseURLForType:@"auth"
                             method:@"loginfundraiser"]
          parameters:parameters
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              NSDictionary *responseDict = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
              NSDictionary *userInfo = nil;

              _authToken = responseDict[kAuthToken];

              if ([responseDict[@"Successful"] boolValue]) {
                  userInfo = @{ kAuthToken: responseObject[kAuthToken] };
              } else {
                  userInfo = @{ @"error": [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"Authorization"
                                                                     code:-1000
                                                                 userInfo:@{ @"message": responseDict[@"ExtendedMessages"] }] };
              }

              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kLoginComplete
                                                                  object:nil
                                                                userInfo:userInfo];
          }

          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ @"error": error };
              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kLoginComplete
                                                                  object:nil
                                                                userInfo:userInfo];
          }];
     }

     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ @"error": error };
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kLoginComplete
                                                             object:nil
                                                           userInfo:userInfo];
     }];
}
```

Comment: AFNetworking dispatches its completion block to the main queue, so if you block the main thread with a semaphore, the completion blocks will deadlock.

Comment: in that case it would be a much better pattern to post a notification after the login is done, and all classes, which need to do further procedures, subscribe to receive that notification, and you can carry on without playing with semaphores.

Comment: In the success/failure blocks of the network login method, I send the notification. The problem is testing, how can I suspend the testing until the network notification is received? Can I tell AFNetworking to use a different queue for block calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay... the primary problem was the queues for AFNetworking **AND** the Notification were on the main thread. The semaphore is blocking the main thread, so **both** responses were blocked.

For the testing, a new NSOperationQueue had to be specified in place of the mainQueue.
For the networking class, a new completionQueue had to be specified. There doesn't seem to be a way of setting a default completionQueue on these methods. Issue has been opened regarding this.

New test code and subset of the network shown below.

```
@implementation NetworkTests

NSOperationQueue * testOperationQueue;

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    testOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
}

- (void)testLogin {
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kLoginComplete
                                                      object:nil
                                                       queue:testOperationQueue
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                      XCTAssertTrue(true, @"login Complete"); // expand on this when I get basic premise working
                                                      NSLog(@"asserted true");
                                                      dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
                                                  }];


    [Network loginWithUserName:@"testname" password:@"password"];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}

@end
```

For the network, it has this:

```
static dispatch_queue_t completionQueue; // initialized when the _gatewayClient object is created

+ (void)loginWithUserName:(NSString *)userName password:(NSString *)password {
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *outerOperation =
    [Network.gatewayClient
     GET:[self baseURLForType:@"auth"
                       method:@"getpubtoken"]
     parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         // do stuff here
     }

     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ @"error": error };
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kLoginComplete
                                                             object:nil
                                                           userInfo:userInfo];
     }];

    outerOperation.completionQueue = completionQueue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i know it is too late for answering.just for those coming to this thread 
afnetwork manager has a completion queue that its default is main queue .
you can change it to another queue like background queue to avoid locking
 `[AFHTTPSessionManager manager].completionQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);`